# Control a Windows application installed on a virtual Windows machine via a Python API?

Tags: windows, macos

I have installed an application (which only works on Windows) on my MacOS (Ventura) in a virtual Windows machine (ParallelsDesktop). I would like to control this application via a Python API.

Are there any settings needed for this, as the connection doesn't seem to be working at the moment?

In order to do this, I think I need to open up the firewall of my virtual Windows machine to accept outside requests (but make sure I'm on an internal network and not opening the Windows machine for the entire internet).

However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [Access Windows Virtual Machine Localhost from Host Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141677/access-windows-virtual-machine-localhost-from-host-mac) help?

Comment: The default for VirtualBox, VMware and Parallels is for the host and guest to be on an internal network, where the guest is not opened to the entire network. Is there some reason you do not think this is happening?